# Как убрать некрасивый перенос в Title="Справочник"?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MobileApp.AppSport" NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false" BackgroundColor="SkyBlue">
    
    <ContentPage Title="Главная">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to the Gym App!" 
                   FontSize="Large"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>

    <!-- Directory Page -->
    <ContentPage Title="Справочник">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Directory Page"
                   FontSize="Large"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>

    <!-- Settings Page -->
    <ContentPage Title="Настройки">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Settings Page"
                   FontSize="Large"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>

    <!-- Personal Account Page -->
    <ContentPage Title="Личный кабинет">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Personal Account Page"
                   FontSize="Large"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>

</TabbedPage>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уменьшить шрифт, уменьшить отступы.

Comment: Очевидно. Напишите как мне это сделать

Comment: @АлексейНовиков грубовато прозвучало

Comment: `FontSize` другое знаение дать например

Comment: Если прозвучало грубо, то извиняюсь. FontSize пробовал, но выдаёт ошибку, но с Label он работает

Comment: Говорят, что такой возможности нет, если только определять CustomRenderer, то есть простого способа нет, так же говорят, что это не будет исправлено. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8519 Есть более новая платформа для разработки андройд-приложений - MAUI.